# setting liquibase.changelogSchemaName property in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am facing issue while setting the changelogSchemaName for liquibase in spring boot.

I am setting it like below -
spring.datasource.datsourcename.liquibase.changelogSchemaName =

But it seems spring boot is not reading this property.

How can this property be set. My problem is I want to use separate schema for changelog tables which i s different from actual schema.

Comment: I guess prefix is `spring.liquibase` without datasource find out more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html). So it should be `spring.liquibase.default-schema`

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=
in your application.properties file for the springboot app.